# Add multiple sheet value criteria based

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an attendance register, needed to be maintained as monthwise separate sheets.  Each sheet adds number of leaves taken under each heading by a person.  This needs to be summarized on a single sheet for each person from different sheets.  The order of people in sheets may vary.

[image]
How do I achieve this please?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me..I had missed out on accepting those answers...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine all the individual monthly sheets. ([Jerry Beaucaire](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/merge-functions/sheets-to-1-sheet) has a macro to do this if manually is too tedious). Because you specify “*need to maintain as monthwise separate sheets*”, from the combined sheet each month filter each month for the required month and then copy the result to a new sheet with an appropriate name.

**Create your summary with a pivot table**. This is much more versatile for analysis and altogether avoids the need for formulae to achieve the result you want. If you want the summary for each person on a separate sheet (“*needs to be summarized on single sheet for each person from different sheets*”) filter the summary and copy the result to separate sheets. However if you mean summarized for every person on a single sheet there is no need for filtering and copying - the pivot table is sufficient.